# Absolute or relative URL in $http(config);

Tags: angularjs, angular-http-interceptors

I'm programming a interceptor in angular and I have a question about the config object  specifically the URL atribute because in the documentation say that have the " Absolute or relative URL of the resource that is being requested" but actually some method are give relative route and another the absolute so how can do to all method give me a relative route?

the config object documetation https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#usage

Comment: uh... What? I mean... What?

Comment: sorry @MarcoAurélioDeleu maybe I was not be clear, the question is in what cases the route is relative and in what is absolute and why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your UI and your web service reside on the same URL, then you can resort to using relative paths. This is because in a relative path, it assumes the base URL from which the UI was served.

However, if your webservice lives at http://a.b.com and your ui lives at http://myUI.com then you will need to include an absolute path.